# Can't find a particular message in Apple Mail on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, search, apple-mail

I can't find a particular message in my mails using Apple Mail on Mac OS X Lion. It connects to my mail server by IMAP.

1. I select my inbox (the one I want to search)
2. On the top right corner I have a search field.
3. I start typing the string I want to find.

It displays no records found, but I'm absolutely sure that this email exists. I've found it on my webmail interface.

If I restrict my search to "Subject", I can find some of those messages containing that string in the subject. If I switch to "Entire Message", that same message can no longer be found.

Comment: It would be nice to show a real-life example with screenshots.

Comment: What's your search term(s)?